# React context warning: "Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: setAuth is not a function at handleEmailLogin"

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a react context called `AuthContext`, which is composed of `[auth, setAuth]`. My handleEmailLogin form does this, and got a warning:

```
  Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: setAuth is not a function at handleEmailLogin
```

While this is only a warning and not an error, what am I doing wrong?

```
const handleEmailLogin = async (values, actions) => {
    setMessage({}); //clear error messages
    const { resetForm, setSubmitting } = actions;

    const { data, error } = await postData({
      url: "/api/account/login",
      data: values
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setMessage({ type: "error", content: error.message.toUpperCase() });
    } else {
      console.log("post data success", data);
      //set context values
      const { session, user } = data;

      const userData = {
        access_token: session.access_token,
        refresh_token: session.refresh_token,
        expires_at: session.expires_at,
        email: user.email,
        google_metadata: null, //if user logged in with google,
        is_email_verified: Boolean(user.email_confirmed_at),
        provider: user.app_metadata.provider,
        token_type: session.token_type,
        uid: user.id
      };
      setAuth(Object.assign({}, auth, userData));
    }

    setSubmitting(false);
    resetForm(initialValues);
  };


//AuthContext.js
import { createContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext([
  {
    access_token: null,
    refresh_token: null,
    expires_at: null,
    expires_in: null,
    email: null,
    google_metadata: null, //if user logged in with google,
    is_email_verified: null,
    provider: null,
    token_type: null,
    uid: null
  },
  (obj) => obj //use to set the object
]);

export default AuthContext;
```

My layout:
//_app.js

```
        <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>
          <CustomLayout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </CustomLayout>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
```

`submitForm` is an event click inside `Formik`

```
<Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={handleEmailLogin}
          >
```

Comment: There's probably not enough code here to really help you. How are you expecting setAuth to be in scope?

Comment: I just added code for AuthContext